# Buildozer: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, buildozer, pyyaml

Running buildozer and getting  error:

```
$ buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yaml (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)`
ERROR: No matching distribution found for yaml (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))`
```

However the module seems to be installed:

```
$ pip3 show pyyaml | grep Version
Version: 5.3.1
$ python
>>> import yaml
>>>
```

The module is ofcourse mentioned in buildozer.spec:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,yaml
```

Also the entire aplication is running ok and without error

```
$ python main.py
```

- Python 3.7.7
- Buildozer 1.2.0
- PyYAML: 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is yaml vs pyyaml.

In python you import yaml, but to install it and reference in buildozer you use pyyaml

buildozer.spec:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,pyyaml
```

To check if you have it installed run the mentioned `pip3 show pyyaml | grep Version`

Or try to import it in python `>>> import yaml`
If you don't have it installed just type

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Hope this helps someone.